# Why use return for methods that do not need a return value？

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I read the source code, I found that the author will use return where there is no need to use return.

[http-party/node-portfinder](https://github.com/http-party/node-portfinder/blob/master/lib/portfinder.js#L145)

```js
exports.getPort = function (options, callback) {
    // code...
    return _async.eachSeries(exports._defaultHosts, function(host, next) {
        // code ...
        return next();
    }
}
```

What is the purpose or need of this usage?

Comment: You dont show full code (...) so you know better than me at this point. But since its a guessing game, that inner return, overrides the outer return.

Answer (score 0):

next is likely a promise.
Maybe in your code it is not used (no then / catch), but there might (and should) be some.

In case the promise was not returned then there is no way to catch errors or make sequentials asynchronous calls.